# Java Writer Readonly File System Exception

Tags: java

I want to write a file 6 folders above me using the buffered writer, but it says it's a read only file system

```java
public static void writeDataToCSVFile() {
    try(
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("/../../../../../../customers.csv")));
    ) {
        writer.write("Id;Firstname;Lastname;Street;Housenumber;Postalcode;City;Country");
        writer.newLine();
        for(Customer customer: CustomerManagement.customers) {
            writer.write(customer.convertToCSVString());
            writer.newLine();
        }
        writer.flush();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /../../../../../../customers.csv: Read-only file system
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:218)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:484)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:228)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(Files.java:3008)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(Files.java:3056)
    at de.volkswagen.fakultaet73.shoppingsystem.management.CustomerManagement.writeDataToCSVFile(CustomerManagement.java:128)
    at de.volkswagen.fakultaet73.shoppingsystem.enities.ShoppingSystem.start(ShoppingSystem.java:23)
    at de.volkswagen.fakultaet73.shoppingsystem.main.Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

When I use the absolute file path, like "/Username/Desktop/test.csv", it works.

Comment: What do you mean by "above me"? Relative paths will be relative to the current working directory. That may or may not match with your notion of "me". Did you check what `Paths.get("/../../../../../../costumers.csv")`.toAbsolutePath()` prints?

Comment: Besides: you wrap a newly created `BufferedWriter` inside another `BufferedWriter`. This will work, but won't give you any benefit (and waste some memory). Simply remove the `new BufferedWriter(...)` wrapping the `Files.newBufferedWriter` call. There's also no need to call `flush()` at that point: closing the writer will automatically flush all relevant buffers for you.

Comment: A path starting with `/` is an absolute path. If you want a relative path, remove the first `/`.

Comment: What is your Opeating System?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to write to the `/` root directory. Generally the root directory isn't writable by regular users.

You want to prefix the directory path with a `.`. `/../../../../../../` is not a valid path. It basically means 6 directories above the `/` root  directory. By definition there are no directories above the root.